# re-styling JQueryMobile - changing the width of a textbox

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Moving beyond a basic grasp of JQueryMobile I find myself wanting to get a little under the hood and change the styling. Consider these form elements: http://jsfiddle.net/mckennatim/rJNeD/

I'd like to have:

```
from $37,400 up to $[textbox here]
```

on one line. How could I change the width of some textbox and keep it 'mobile' looking?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>  

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="calcs" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>graphics2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="#" method="get">
            <div  id="ratelist">
                <legend><b>Ordinary Tax Rates</b></legend>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <input type="range" name="slider" id="rate4" value="30" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" />up to $: <br/>                           
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="178653" data-mini="true"/><br/>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">              
                <label for="slider">% rate:</label>
                    <input type="range" name="slider" id="rate5" value="33" min="0" max="70" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" /><br/>
                    <label for="slider">up to $</label>
                    <input type="range" name="slider" id="upto5" value="388350" min="0" max="3000000" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" /><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>test</h4>
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to target the form input and change any CSS property for the element. If you want to change the `width` of the `#name` element you would add this CSS to your document:

```
#name {
    width : 200px;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rJNeD/3/

Since `#name` is not a very unique ID and could inadvertently be added to the site more than once, you could specify which page in your CSS rule:

```
#calcs #name {
    width : 200px;
}​
```

Comment: Pity this has stopped working in JQM 1.3.0 (with JQ 1.9): http://jsfiddle.net/rJNeD/314/

Comment: @Marc It looks like now there is a wrapper element around the `<input type="text />` element that gives the visual style, it's got this class: `ui-input-text`. That makes sense because different browsers put different limitations on how you can style a form input.